# Swing Timer is only calling two of three methods when it fires

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm writing a simple roulette game where a user can add players, place bets and spin the roulette wheel (represented as a JLabel which updates its text to show roulette numbers)

```
public void spin(int wheelSize, int initialDelay, int finalDelay,
    int delayIncrement, WheelCallback callback) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int curNo = rand.nextInt(wheelSize) + 1;
    int finalNo = 0;

    int count = 10;

    assert (curNo >= 1);

    Listener myListener = new Listener(callback, this, curNo);
    myListener.start(finalDelay);
```

The class `Listener`:

```
package model;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import model.interfaces.*;
import model.GameEngineImpl;
import model.WheelCallbackImpl;

public class Listener implements ActionListener {

WheelCallbackImpl callback;
GameEngineImpl engine;
Timer timer;
int delay, curNo, finalNo;
int count = 10;

public Listener(WheelCallbackImpl wheelcall, GameEngineImpl newEngine, int number) {
    callback = wheelcall;
    engine = newEngine;
    curNo = number;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (count == 0) {
        engine.calculateResult(finalNo);

        callback.result(finalNo, engine);

        callback.playback();

        timer.stop();
    } else {
        callback.nextNumber(curNo, engine);
        curNo++;

        finalNo = curNo;
        count--;

    }
}

public void start(int delay) {
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
}

}
```

`Listener` communicates with a helper class `WheelCallbackImpl`, which handles user feedback and communicates with my View:

```
 public class WheelCallbackImpl implements WheelCallback {

Wheel wcWheel = Wheel.myWheel;

public void nextNumber(int nextNumber, GameEngine engine) {

    String strNo = Integer.toString(nextNumber);

    assert (nextNumber >= 1);

    System.out.println(nextNumber);

    wcWheel.setCounter(strNo);
}

public void result(int result, GameEngine engine) {

    System.out.println("callback.Result is running!");

    Collection<Player> players = engine.getAllPlayers();

    Player[] playerList = players.toArray(new Player[0]);

    System.out.println("Player list length is " + playerList.length);

    for (int i=0; i < playerList.length; i++) {

        if (playerList[i].getNumberPick() == result) 
            wcWheel.storeResults(playerList[i].getPlayerName(), playerList[i].getPoints(), " won!", i);         
        else
            wcWheel.storeResults(playerList[i].getPlayerName(), playerList[i].getPoints(), " lost!", i);
    }

    System.out.println("callback.result finished!");
}

/*
    Called by the controller - calls the GUI display/replay prompts
*/
public void playback() {
    System.out.println("Playback called!");

    int n = 0;

    while (n == 0)
        wcWheel.playAgain();
}

}
```

My `Timer` is able to update my JLabel successfully, however when it executes the `if (count == 0)` block, it seems to only call the first *two* methods, leaving me with this output:

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
Calculate result called!
callback.Result is running!
Player list length is 1
callback.result finished!
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

**IF** everything is as you posted, then this seems to me as an *impossible* result:

```
callback.result(finalNo, engine);
callback.playback();
```

You say that `callback.result()` is called whose last statement is a `System.out.println()` which is visible on the console however the first `System.out.println()` statement of `callback.playback();` is not visible on the console.

Either you modified your code and did not recompile it, or the result of `callback.playback()` IS visible but you need to scroll your console window to see it.